# Error When Creating CLR Function

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I've created an C# class that contains 2 static method and I successfully created an Assembly in SQL 2005.  When I try to create a table-valued function from that Assembly I get the following error:

> Msg 6509, Level 16, State 36, Procedure , Line 2
>   An error occurred while gathering metadata from assembly '' with HRESULT 0x80004005.

We have other CLR functions that are that are with in the same dll and seem to work fine.  I tried to emulate what the other functions are doing, but I can't seem to get this function to work.

All the documentation online doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I changed the return value in the C# method to IEnumerable insted of DataTable and WALLLLLA. 
no problem.

GOOD LUCK

tsadok